# Can I run a Manova after conducting a cluster analysis?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, manova, statsmodels

So my study intends to conduct a cluster analysis using 2 variables (RP and AP).

I intend to find four clusters (AC, BC, CC and DC).

I would then like to examine differences in education, height, age, and weight amongst the identified clusters (AC, BC, CC and DC).

How would I go about examining this? Do I just create a new label for all the participants by assigning them into their assigned cluster then running a manova (4 IV [AC, BC, CC, and DC] - and 4 DV (education, height, age, and weight])?

Thank you for helping me out, I really appreciate all the insight from everyone!

Comment: Too short for an answer: yes, you can, provided that the assumptions of MANOVA are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for responding Galen! Can you please elaborate on what you mean by assumptions of MANOVA? Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: e.g. (approximate) normality, or homoschedasticity of residuals.